# how can i send an email when user register but to the specific email in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-8

I need when a user registers successfully to send notification email to the reference email field

the notification include one line text with link buttom and when he click on the buttom will redirect to my website

I need to send that notification to the **referance_email** field

```
public function create(array $input)
    {   $massage = ['tc_no_pasaport_no.unique'=> 'Sorry, internal error .',
        'phone.unique'=>'Sorry, internal error .' ];


        
       Validator::make($input, [
            'phone' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255','unique:users'],

            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            
            'tc_no_pasaport_no' => ['required','max:11','unique:users'],
            'place_of_birth' => ['required'],
            'date_of_birth' => ['required'],
            'educational_status' => ['required','string'],
            'school_department' => ['required'],
            'address' => ['required'],
           



            'password' => $this->passwordRules(),
            'terms' => Jetstream::hasTermsAndPrivacyPolicyFeature() ? ['required', 'accepted'] : '',
        ],$massage)->validate();

        $users = User::where('email', '=', $input['email'])->first();
            if ($users === null) {
            return User::create([



            'name' => $input['name'],
            'email' => $input['email'],
            'phone' => $input['phone'],

            'password' => Hash::make($input['password']),
            'membership_status' =>'pasif',
            'membership_type' =>'standard',
            'last_activation_date' =>  Carbon::now(),
            'membership_end_date' =>  Carbon::now(),     
            'temporary_id' => random_int(1000000, 9999999),
            'tc_no_pasaport_no' => $input['tc_no_pasaport_no'],
            'place_of_birth' => $input['place_of_birth'],
            'date_of_birth' => $input['date_of_birth'],
            'educational_status' => $input['educational_status'],
            'school_department' => $input['school_department'],
            'Institution_and_unit' => $input['Institution_and_unit'],
            'address' => $input['address'],
            'referance_email' => $input['referance_email'],
            'letter_of_Intent'=>$input['letter_of_Intent'],
            'created_at' => Carbon::now(),


        ]);

    }
```

Comment: I think you want to send email verification email to user? right? Then use the laravel's `MustVerifyEmail` system. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/verification#the-email-verification-notice

Comment: I want to send a notification to the reference email that the user entered and not to the user himself
i mean send an email to this field
'referance_email' => $input['referance_email'],

Comment: Then use the `laravel Mail` https://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/laravel_sending_email.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PHP Mailer library to send email in PHP.